# Initialization of simple bool vector in c++ fails

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I am trying to initialize a simple vector with false values and then use it.
I rellized the value is never 0 or 1, so I printed it. The result is that even in the beginning it has strange big values. I am compiling with g++ (GCC) 4.4.7.
The question refers to printing only vector data of type bool.

What I did:

```
std::vector<bool> n;
int f = 0;
for(f = 0; f<10; f++)
    n.push_back(false);
for(f = 0; f<10; f++)
    printf("content of %d %d",f,n[f]);
```

What I got:

```
content of 0 30572784
content of 1 30572784
content of 2 30572784
content of 3 30572784
content of 4 30572784
content of 5 30572784
content of 6 30572784
content of 7 30572784
content of 8 30572784
content of 9 30572784
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is combining type-unsafe C library functions, like `printf()`, with C++ code. Do not use `printf` in C++. Use `std::cout`.

Comment: `printf` format string does not match input because `n[f]` is not an `int`. You should've got a corresponding compilation warning.

Comment: [`vector<bool>` is an odd beastie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). You might be better off [with a `std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: use cout + http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha if you want true/false instead of 1/0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf("%f",0); give undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597274/why-does-printff-0-give-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `%d` is for `int`(32bits), but to make a `vector` of `bool` more space efficient, `vector<bool>` is a specialized class that stores a bool as a single bit by using a proxy class. And, `operator []` actually returns a reference of that proxy class (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

If you want to use `printf`, you'd need to cast it to a bool first

```
for(f = 0; f<10; f++)
    printf("content of %d %d",f,bool(n[f]));
```

Or, as others have mentioned in the Comments, use `cout` in C++.

```
cout << "content of " << f <<" " << n[f];
```

If you want to see true/false, you can also use `std::boolalpha`

```
cout << boolalpha << "content of " << f <<" " << n[f]; //will see true/false
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a bool vector, you can use fill constructor as given in documentation 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

```
std::vector<bool> n(10, false); (*)
```