# Function doesn't return correct value using pointers in C

Tags: c

This is a program to calculate the prize for all friends who contributed for a bet. The reward is based on how much each one contributed with money. But the function i created is returning 0.0000 for all.

a little dictionary:

- premio = prize
- aposta = contribution of each friend

```
int main(){
    int exerc;

    printf("Digite o numero do exercicio desejado: ");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &exerc);

    switch (exerc){
        case 2:{
            float aposta1, aposta2, aposta3, premio;

            printf("Digite respectivamente o valor que cada um apostou: ");
            scanf("%d %d %d", &aposta1, &aposta2, &aposta3);
            printf("Digite o valor do premio: ");
            scanf("%d", &premio);

            void exercicio2(float *, float*, float*, const float*);
            exercicio2(&aposta1, &aposta2, &aposta3, &premio);

            printf("O valor que o primeiro apostante recebera e de: %f", aposta1);
            printf("\nO valor que o segundo apostante recebera e de: %f", aposta2);
            printf("\nO valor que o terceiro apostante recebera e de: %f", aposta3);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void exercicio2(float *ap1, float *ap2, float *ap3, const float *premio){
    float total;

    total = *ap1 + *ap2 + *ap3;

    *ap1 = (*ap1/total) * (*premio);
    *ap2 = (*ap2/total) * (*premio);
    *ap3 = (*ap3/total) * (*premio);
}
```

An expected value for input (bets) aposta1 = 50, aposta2 = 25, aposta3 = 25 and premio(prize) = 1000, would be: ap1 = 500, ap2 = 250, ap3 = 250.

but it's occurring:

```
"C:\Users\Marco Antonio\CLionProjects\untitled\cmake-build-debug\untitled.exe"
Digite o numero do exercicio desejado: 2
Digite respectivamente o valor que cada um apostou:50 25 25
Digite o valor do premio:1000
O valor que o primeiro apostante recebera e de: 0.000000
O valor que o segundo apostante recebera e de: 0.000000
O valor que o terceiro apostante recebera e de: 0.000000
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d", &aposta1, &aposta2, &aposta3);` Use `%f` for `float`s instead.

Comment: Using the wrong format specifier has undefined behaviour. A decent compiler should be warning you about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the format specifier ( `%d` to `%f` ) will solve the issue:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &aposta1, &aposta2, &aposta3);
scanf("%d", &premio);
```

to

```
scanf("%f %f %f", &aposta1, &aposta2, &aposta3);
scanf("%f", &premio);
```

The issue was you are entering a floating point number and your program is reading the integer. In such case, the behaviour is undefined. Please take a look at a [SO question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597274/why-does-printff-0-give-undefined-behavior) about format specifier and undefined behaviour.

Standard specifies:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.