# Outputing integer as float in printf_s function

Tags: c++

Having such simple C++ instructions:

```
int f1 = 3238;

printf_s("Printf_1.cpp 1 - float: %d\n", f1);
printf_s("Printf_1.cpp 2 - float: %f\n", f1);
```

The output of the second `printf_s` is `0.000000` My question is why there isn't just `3238.000000`? What happened with `3238` integral part of the number?

PS.
My specs: Win 10, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

Comment: You are lying to printf about the type of argument. Undefined Behaviour follows.

Comment: dupe of [Why does printf("%f",0); give undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597274/why-does-printff-0-give-undefined-behavior) et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` requires variable argument types to match your format specifiers. In particular, `%f` expects you to pass `double`, and you pass `int`. `printf` interprets bytes of your `int` in that way so it prints out `0.000000`, but in general there is no warranty what such combination should produce (and that's called "Undefined Behavior"). What you need to do is add explicit typecast to double: `printf("%f", (double) f1)`.